# EV3 software crashes when coding color sensor switch, how can I fix this?

Tags: ev3, programming, sensor-colour

When students use the switch block to program the color sensor on their Chromebooks, the app crashes. We have all accessibilities turned off and the OS is fully updated. What other troubleshooting steps can we take?

Comment: Have you contacted LEGO technical support?

Comment: Does the application generate any log or dump files that could be analyzed?

Comment: It seems like you are no longer active, so we might have to close your question since you won't send necessary info. You don't show the program. You don't tell when exactly the app crashes. You don't send any dump files. Etc. Your question is too broad

Comment: Leaving the question like this, we will just have to guess what code you wrote and see what happens. All we know is that it involved a switch and a color sensor. Chromebooks usually make different file types than the EV3 software on any other computer.